# Slow display of PDF first time everytime

Tags: pdf, time, load

We are building a web application that makes extensive use of PDFs for display of documents. The first time a user logs into the app, and clicks on a PDF, we are confronted with up to 20-30sec delays to show the PDF, even with small PDFs on reasonably quick connections. Subsequent PDFs display much more quickly. While displaying the first PDF, the HD churns extensively on some machines. SSD machines load the first PDF in 2-5 secs. Chrome, with its built-in PDF viewer is a non-issue.

Obviously, the problem lies with the Acrobat Reader plugin.

Can we invisibly load a PDF on user login so as to get the plugin ready? Is there an alternative solution to have a "built-in" mechanism for IE6+ and FF3+?

Comment: You've verified that the problem is on the client and not the server?

Comment: The "obviously" may have been presumptuous, but it seems to be the case. Only the first PDF opens slowly, no matter which PDF is chosen or size thereof, and all subsequent do so slowly. The PDF that opened slowly the first time opens fast if opened second. Close the browser and re-open and/or reboot and the issue repeats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is just the launch time for Reader/Acrobat.  You can easily verify this by opening Reader then going to the site.  If the delay vanishes, you'll know the cause.

You could ask your users to open Reader first.  Meh.

Programmatically, the only thing I can think of would be to open a dummy PDF in another window/tab in the background.  You could set that PDF's "open action" to close itself (via script).  The user will see a window appearing and disappearing.

Hmm... You can stick a PDF in an `<object>` tag.  I wonder if Acrobat would play nice if you set that object to be invisible?  That might be browser-specific, but is worth looking into.